# IBAction Error from answer in July 2011

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This answer was given in July 2011 to a question asked by Amar H-V July 5, '11:

In your code, add the method to handle that action. For instance,

```
.h file

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender;
.m file

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
  NSLog(@"Button Tapped!");
}
```

Now, open you xib file, right click to File's Owner, there you should see your method, drag the plus circle onto your button. You should see a bunch of different actions, most of the time touchUpInside is what you are looking for.

I'm using Xcode 6.2 and in the .h file I'm getting the error message !Expected a type and the caret is under theU in (UIButton).

Is there a way to make this work in Xcode 6.2?

Thanks
Keith

Comment: Good weed you smoke sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your header doesn't know what a `UIButton` is
Add

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Or

```
@class UIButton;
```

Comment: I do apologize for the poorly worded question. Upon reflection I know how to better ask this question. All I have to do now is figure out how to connect the button to the code.